# Create UserControl ComboBox with Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, user-controls

I'm trying to create an UserControl that have a ComboBox with a list of items and then I want to add a button to perform some action.

I have this code:

ComboBoxWithButton XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-1" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Source}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding }" Width="100" />
                    <Button Grid.Column="1">Something</Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

ComboBoxWithButton Code:

```
public ComboBoxWithButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProprety =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(ComboBoxWithButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ObservableCollection<object> Source
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(ValueProprety); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProprety, value); }
        }
```

Then on my Window I call:

```
<controls:ComboBoxWithButton Source="{Binding SomeCollection}"/>
```

But the combobox is empty

Comment: "I'm not getting any listing" Are you saying the combo box is empty? Try binding `ItemsSource="{Binding Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"` on the combo box in your usercontrol XAML. BTW `Source` needn't be `ObservableCollection`; make it non-generic `IEnumerable` to allow consumers the broadest possible lattitude in what they give you. `ComboBox.ItemsSource` is `IEnumerable`. The combobox will figure things out.

Comment: Yes that was what I meant. Changing how you said is still the same

Comment: Try fixing your `Source` property, by the way. `GetValue(SourceProperty)`, `SetValue(SourceProperty, value)`. Don't use `ValueProperty` there. I don't think that's causing this problem, but it's definitely a bug.

Comment: Try fixing the name of `SourceProprety`. It's misspelled. It needs to be `SourceProperty`.

Comment: Yes, that was a bug, but keeps the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make three changes in your dependency property: Change its type to `System.Collections.IEnumerable` (non-generic), correct the name of `SourceProprety` to `SourceProperty`, and use `SourceProperty` rather than `ValueProperty` in your calls to `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` (that last bug won't affect the `ComboBox`, because a `Binding` will call `SetValue()` and `GetValue()` directly, but it's still a bug):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("Source", 
         typeof(IEnumerable), 
         typeof(ComboBoxWithButton), 
         new PropertyMetadata(null));

public IEnumerable Source
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
}
```

Your definition of the property required the collection to be of type `ObservableCollection<object>`. Only `object`, nothing but `object`. If you bound `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` to it, it would fail to populate the `ComboBox`. [`ComboBox.ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) is of type `System.Collections.IEnumerable` (the property is inherited from `ItemsControl`). Stick with that. It works. Any `ObservableCollection` of anything can be bound to that. Let the `ComboBox` figure out the details; that's what it does best.

Next, your binding is looking at the `UserControl`'s `DataContext` for the `Source` property, but it's a property of the `UserControl` itself. Here's how to fix that:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="ComboBoxBtn" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="0,0,0,-1" 
    Width="100" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
    >
```

The XAML designer may give you a blue squiggle under the `ItemsSource` line. Let it moan, it just gets confused sometimes.

Comment: I have that blue squiggle. Says that can't find controls. And If I run it throws an exception

Comment: @AndreRoque You defined `controls` yourself. I copied it from your question. If it's not defined in your UserControl XAML, you should be able to define it there. Anyway, try `UserControl` instead of `controls:ComboBoxWithButton`. I updated my answer to do it that way.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!